# I successfully compiled my program. Now how do I run it?

Tags: javascript, pdf, compilation

I want to solve [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) [Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1):

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*\rfrac[2]{{}^{#1}\!/_{#2}}
\title{Solution to Project Euler Problem 1}
\author{Aadit M Shah}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
We want to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. We can use the formula of the $n^{th}$ triangular number\footnote{\url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number}} to calculate the sum of all the multiples of a number $m$ below 1000. The formula of the $n^{th}$ triangular number is:

\begin{equation}
T_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n k = 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n = \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}
\end{equation}

If the last multiple of $m$ below 1000 is $x$ then $n = \rfrac{x}{m}$. The sum of all the multiples of $m$ below 1000 is therefore:

\begin{equation}
m \times T_{\frac{x}{m}} = m \times \sum_{k = 1}^{\frac{x}{m}} k = \frac{x (\frac{x}{m} + 1)}{2}
\end{equation}

Thus the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 is equal to:

\begin{equation}
3 \times T_{\frac{999}{3}} + 5 \times T_{\frac{995}{5}} - 15 \times T_{\frac{990}{15}} = \frac{999 \times 334 + 995 \times 200 - 990 \times 67}{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I compiled it successfully using `pdflatex`:

```
$ pdflatex Problem1.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
.
.
.
Output written on Problem1.pdf (1 page, 106212 bytes).
Transcript written on Problem1.log.
```

It generated the following output PDF file along with a bunch of other files with scary extensions:

[image: Solution to Project Euler Problem 1]

How do I run this PDF file so that it computes the solution? I know the solution to the problem but I want to know how to execute the PDF file to compute the solution.

The reason why I prefer LaTeX over other programming languages is because it supports [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming), an approach to programming introduced by [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth), the creator of [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) and one of the greatest computer scientists of all time.

**Edit:** It would also be nice to be able to print the computed solution either on the screen or on paper. Computing the solution without printing it is useful for heating the room but it is so hot already with the onset of summer and global warming. In addition, printing the solution would teach me how to write a hello world program in LaTeX.

Comment: "april-fools" tag ... ? :)

Comment: Isn't it obvious? You need to compile to postscript, not to pdf, then you can run the program on your printer.

Comment: @Bergi That's actually a really good idea.

Comment: Maybe just copy paste it into Wolfram Alpha. That's how all the big math wizzes do it.

Comment: I'm sorry to close-vote this "Fools days" question - but I think it is just a tad to off-topic

Comment: I think this can easily be solved using a built-in Linux feature. Just do the following:
    Problem1.tex > /dev/null; /dev/urandom > Problem1-Solution.txt

Comment: @RohanDurve-Decode141 And hope that the [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) generates the correct solution before I die? Hopefully, they are [Markovian monkeys](http://blog.javascriptroom.com/2013/01/21/markov-chains/).

Comment: Hey, the answer is out there, you only need to show the initiative to look for it. The SO community is more about the process behind the solution than supplying answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*So, today seems to be a safe day to tackle this problem...*

---

The OP does not seem to be quite so *PDF*-savvy.
However, he obviously is quite a literate *LaTeX* guy.
Which means, he also must be knowing TeX very well, given he is so much of a Donald Knuth admirer...

So much for the preliminaries.
Now for the real meat.

**First,** to quote **[the official PDF-1.7 specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)** document:

> *PDF is not a programming language, and a PDF file is not a program.*
>                                                                                                               (p. 92, Section 7.10.1)

However, the pre-decessor of the PDF format, PostScript, ***IS*** a **[Turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)** programming language... Turing-complete, just as **[TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)** is, the creation of **[Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)**, one of the greatest computer scientists of all time.

PostScript files, on the other hand, ***ARE*** programs, and can easily be executed by PostScript printers (though this execution time cannot reliably be determined in advance).

Hence, and ***second***, the OP should be able to find a way to convert his hi-level LaTeX code to low-level TeX code.
That code needs to emit a PostScript program, which in turn can be executed by a PostScript printer.
Writing that TeX code should be trivial for somebody like the OP, once he is given the PostScript code that should be the result of his TeX code.

I myself am not so well-versed with the TeX aspect of that problem solving procedure.
However, I can help with the PostScript.

The PostScript which the OP's TeX code should produce goes like this (there are for sure more optimized versions possible -- this is only a first, quick'n'dirty shot at it):

```
%!PS

% define variables
/n1 999 def
/t1 334 def
/n2 995 def
/t2 200 def
/n3 990 def
/s1  67 def
/t3   2 def

% run the computational code
n1 t1 mul
n2 t2 mul
n3 s1 mul
sub
add
t3    div

% print result on printer, not on <stdout>
/Helvetica findfont
24 scalefont
setfont
30 500 moveto
(Result for 'Project Euler Problem No. 1' :) show 
/Helvetica-Bold findfont
48 scalefont
setfont
80 400 moveto
(                   ) cvs show 
showpage
```

Send this PostScript code to a PostScript printer, and it will compute and print the solution.

---

### Update

To answer one of the comments: If you replace the last section of PostScript code starting with `/Helvetica findfont` with a simple `print` statement, it will not do what you might imagine.

`print` does not cause the printer to output paper. Instead it asks the PostScript interpreter to write the topmost item on the stack (which must be a `(string)`!) to the standard output channel. (If the topmost item on the stack is not of type `(string)`, it will trigger a `typecheck` PostScript error.)

So sending a modified PostScript file (where `print` has replaced the last section of my PS code) to the printer will not work (unless that printer supports the interactive *`executive`* PostScript mode -- which is not a standard part of the PostScript language). It will work however if you feed that file to *Ghostscript* in a terminal or `cmd.exe` window.

Comment: Hey Kurt, it's a shame that PDF is neither a programming language nor a program. At least now I know that I need to convert my LaTeX code into TeX code which generates a PostScript file which computes and prints the solution. I updated my question to reflect the fact that not only do I want to compute the solution but also print it. Thank you for the PostScript code. That was very helpful.

Comment: Then you did so despite of the typos I still have in my quick'n'dirty PostScript code. Hadn't testrun it (still haven't) but now I spotted two errors. To be fixed now...

Comment: It is still wrong. It should be `n1 t1 mul n2 t2 mul n3 s1 mul sub add t3 div` (i.e. the first `add` should be a `sub` if I am not mistaken). Problems of using a concatenative programming language.

Comment: Can I add a `print` after the expression to print it out (i.e. `... sub add t3 div print`)? I don't know much about PostScript.

Comment: @AaditMShah: you are right about the `sub` (I didn't pay enough attention to final formula *(3)* when translating it to PostScript and remembered it as all being additions).

Comment: @AaditMShah: Using `print` to write the topmost element `(string)` from stack to `<stdout>`, will cause `(string)` to be gone from stack. So either use `dup print` (which puts a copy of topmost stack element on stack), or use the `pstack` operator (will print complete stack *nondestructively* -- but we'll only have 1 element on the stack anyway). Because of 'nondestructively' you can use `2345 add dup print` to add 2345 to last result and then print that to `<stdout>`.

Comment: @AaditMShah: I hope you notice that the PS code I gave is (deliberately) a bit more 'convoluted' than it needs to be. If you want it shorter, please do tell.

Comment: I checked the [PDF reference 1.7 at adobe.com](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), and the "PDF is not a programming language" quote seems to actually be in page 166, section 3.9.

Comment: @PandaPajama: Right you are -- but I've not linked in my answer to that edition of the spec which I had in mind (it's the one adopted by the ISO as *'ISO32000'*).

Comment: @AaditMShah: Sorry, had overlooked your question in the comment asking  *"Can I add a `print` after the expression to print it out?"* -- The `print` statement will not cause printer to print on paper. Instead it will cause the PS interpreter to return the string via the `<stdout>` channel, which is not printed on paper... If you test the code via Ghostscript however, you will see what comes back via `<stdout>` in the terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run pdf files. You need to use the `latex` command instead of `pdflatex`. e.g.

```
latex Problem1.tex
```

[Here's some documentation](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~rootd/catdoc/guide/TheGuide_123.html)

Comment: silly me. didn't see the tag. but it's only 3/31 here :)